# javascript create elements dynamically increasing class name number

Tags: javascript

How to dynamically create elements (for example div) and append them to the body increasing their className number, for example: name1, name2, name3, etc.. ??

```
<div class="name1"></div>
<div class="name2"></div>
<div class="name3"></div>
<div class="name4"></div>
```

Comment: what have your tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.setAttribute("class", "name" + (i + 1));
    document.body.appendChild(ele);
}
```

Comment: thank you! is exactly what I want :) I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
  var ele = document.createElement('div');
  ele.className = "name" + 1;
  document.body.appendChild(ele);
}
```

Comment: Used to jQuery, huh? :)

Comment: yeah. A lot. @Derek朕會功夫